# Why Javas Collections framework binary search uses iterator for searching an element in a large list

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

In the java docs:-

> Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm.  The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the {@linkplain Comparable natural ordering} of its elements (as by the {@link #sort(List)} method) prior to making this call.  If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.  If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.
>
> This method runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access).  If the specified list does not implement the {@link RandomAccess} interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.

Why the implementation uses iterator for large list like linked list which do not implement Random Access.

```
public static <T>
    int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key) {
        if (list instanceof RandomAccess || list.size()<BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD)
            return Collections.indexedBinarySearch(list, key);
        else
            return Collections.iteratorBinarySearch(list, key);
    }
```

Comment: What is your confusion? What else do you think it should do?

Comment: I do not understand how the iterator gives better performance for large data structures in the search implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just keep looking at the source code, it's all explained pretty well.
Look for the `BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD` `static` field.

```
/*
 * Tuning parameters for algorithms - Many of the List algorithms have
 * two implementations, one of which is appropriate for RandomAccess
 * lists, the other for "sequential."  Often, the random access variant
 * yields better performance on small sequential access lists.  The
 * tuning parameters below determine the cutoff point for what constitutes
 * a "small" sequential access list for each algorithm.  The values below
 * were empirically determined to work well for LinkedList. Hopefully
 * they should be reasonable for other sequential access List
 * implementations.  Those doing performance work on this code would
 * do well to validate the values of these parameters from time to time.
 * (The first word of each tuning parameter name is the algorithm to which
 * it applies.)
 */
private static final int BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD   = 5000;
```

The engineers who implemented the code you're using determined that was the most optimal trade-off. It's nothing written in stone, so you can just extract

```
iteratorBinarySearch // or
indexedBinarySearch
```

and use them at your will, if you think one would perform better for your specific use-case.

Comment: What is the reason behind using iterator in large lists which do not implement RandomAccess.

Comment: @DakshPratapSingh the reasoning is **benchmarks**. Oracle engineers (because that version comes  from Oracle JDK) benchmarked the performance of the two solutions and observed the Iterator solution perfomed better on larger data-sets.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared my doubt. I thought their was a theoretical reason behind it. Please do not stop contributing after getting 10k points :p.